# calculate area of 2-dimensional confidence ellipse in R

Tags: r, area, ellipse

So I have log-transformed measurement data arranged in a simple table:

```
      x         y
1.158362492 1.322219295
1.1430148   1.267171728
1.11058971  1.252853031
1.120573931 1.260071388
1.149219113 1.278753601
1.123851641 1.276461804
1.096910013 1.222716471
```

I know there are functions for plotting a confidence ellipse for these data, but how to I calculate the area of the generated shape?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First calculate the ellipse, then determine the lengths of the major and minor axes, and then [calculate the area](http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10006.3.shtml).

Here's a brainless approximation.

First, your data.

```
dat <- structure(list(x = c(1.158362492, 1.1430148, 1.11058971, 1.120573931, 
          1.149219113, 1.123851641, 1.096910013), y = c(1.322219295, 1.267171728, 
          1.252853031, 1.260071388, 1.278753601, 1.276461804, 1.222716471
          )), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
          -7L))
```

Then load the package `car`; `dataEllipse` can be used to calculate an ellipse using a bivariate normal approximation to the data.

```
require(car)
dataEllipse(dat$x, dat$y, levels=0.5)
```

A call to `ellipse` can give points along the ellipse that `dataEllipse` plots.

```
me <- apply(dat, 2, mean)
v <- var(dat)
rad <- sqrt(2*qf(0.5, 2, nrow(dat)-1))
z <- ellipse(me, v, rad, segments=1001)
```

We can then calculate the distance from each point on the ellipse to the center.

```
dist2center <- sqrt(rowSums((t(t(z)-me))^2))
```

The minimum and maximum of these distances are the half-lengths of the minor and major axes.  So we can get the area as follows.

```
pi*min(dist2center)*max(dist2center)
```

Comment: "Calculate the ellipse" needs a bit of elaboration.

Comment: @Benjamin - Perhaps I was being overly facetious, but it seemed that the questioner knew how to calculate the ellipse, at which the area wouldn't be difficult, unless there was difficulty making sense of things, in which case he should have asked about that part.

Comment: very nice. The link to "calculate the area" is unfortunately broken. BTW Thanks for your extremely helpful blog on making R packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use package `mclust`, there is a hidden function called `mvn_plot`, the input parameters are `mean` and `std`. You may try to read its code and modify it to get the length of each axis.

Answer (score 0):

The area can be directly calculated from the covariance matrix by calculating the eigenvalues first.

You need to scale the variances / eigenvalues by the factor of confidence that you want to get.

[This thread is very helpful](https://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/draw-error-ellipse-representing-covariance-matrix/)

```r
cov_dat <- cov(dat) # covariance matrix

eig_dat <- eigen(cov(dat))$values #eigenvalues of covariance matrix

vec <- sqrt(5.991* eig_dat) # half the length of major and minor axis for the 95% confidence ellipse

pi * vec[1] * vec[2]  
#> [1] 0.005796157
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

`dat` [from user Karl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7543364/7941188)