# How to calculate the area of ellipse drawn by ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-car

In ggplot2, after I drawing the ellipse plot using stat_ellipse, is there any way to calculate the area of this ellipse? Here is the code and the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm (1:1000)
y <- rnorm (1:1000)
data <- cbind(x, y)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
ggplot (data, aes (x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_ellipse()
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can calculate the area of the ellipse by finding its semi-major and semi-minor axes (as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7543364/496488)):

```
# Plot object
p = ggplot (data, aes (x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_ellipse(segments=201) # Default is 51. We use a finer grid for more accurate area.

# Get ellipse coordinates from plot
pb = ggplot_build(p)
el = pb$data[[2]][c("x","y")]

# Center of ellipse
ctr = MASS::cov.trob(el)$center  # Per @Roland's comment

# Calculate distance to center from each point on the ellipse
dist2center <- sqrt(rowSums((t(t(el)-ctr))^2))

# Calculate area of ellipse from semi-major and semi-minor axes. 
# These are, respectively, the largest and smallest values of dist2center. 
pi*min(dist2center)*max(dist2center)

[1] 13.82067
```

Comment: You can calculate the center more precisely with `MASS::cov.trob(cbind(x, y))$center`, which is what `stat_ellipse` [uses by default](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-ellipse.R#L96).

Comment: after pondering on [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60423973/7941188), I think the answer may not be quite correct - currently you're calculating the center based on the calculated ellipse data points - not based on the data, which @Roland was pointing to. I guess it should be rather either `MASS::cov.trob(pb$data[[1]][c("x","y")])$center` or indeed `MASS::cov.trob(data)$center`

Answer (score 0):

The area can be directly calculated from the covariance matrix by calculating the eigenvalues first.

You need to scale the variances / eigenvalues by the factor of confidence that you want to get.

[This thread is very helpful](https://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/draw-error-ellipse-representing-covariance-matrix/)

```r
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:1000), y = rnorm(1:1000))

cov_dat <- cov(dat) # covariance matrix

eig_dat <- eigen(cov(dat))$values #eigenvalues of covariance matrix

vec <- sqrt(5.991* eig_dat) # half the length of major and minor axis for the 95% confidence ellipse

pi * vec[1] * vec[2]  
#> [1] 18.38858
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**In this particular case, the covariances are zero**, and the eigenvalues will be more or less the variance of the variables. So you can use just the variance for your calculation. - given that both are normally distributed.

```r
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:1000), y = rnorm(1:1000))

pi * 5.991 * sd(data$x) * sd(data$y) # factor for 95% confidence = 5.991
#> [1] 18.41814
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The calculated value is different [from user eipi10's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38782622/7941188). This is likely due to the different calculation under the hood, with different assumptions on the underlying distribution. [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423973/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-ggplot-stat-ellipse-when-type-norm?noredirect=1&lq=1).