# How to calculate the area of a ggplot stat_ellipse() when 'type = "norm"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782051/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-ellipse-drawn-by-ggplot2?noredirect=1&lq=1#_=_)

Is there any way to calculate the area of this ellipse when type = "norm"?

Default is `type = "t"`. `type = "norm"` displays a different ellipse because it assumes a multivariate normal distribution instead of multivariate t-distribution

**Here is the code and the plot (using similar code as other post):**

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:1000), y = rnorm(1:1000))

ggplot (data, aes (x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_ellipse(type = "norm")
```

**Previous answer was:**

```
#Plot object
p = ggplot (data, aes (x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_ellipse(segments=201) # Default is 51. We use a finer grid for more accurate area.

#Get ellipse coordinates from plot

pb = ggplot_build(p)
el = pb$data[[2]][c("x","y")]

# Center of ellipse

ctr = MASS::cov.trob(el)$center 
# I tried changing this to 'stats::cov.wt' instead of 'MASS::cov.trob' 
#from what is saw from (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-ellipse.R#L98)

# Calculate distance to center from each point on the ellipse

dist2center <- sqrt(rowSums((t(t(el)-ctr))^2))

# Calculate area of ellipse from semi-major and semi-minor axes. 
These are, respectively, the largest and smallest values of dist2center. 

pi*min(dist2center)*max(dist2center)
```

Changing to `stats::cov.wt` wasn't enough to get the area of the "norm" ellipse (value calculated was the same). Any ideas on how to change the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nice first question. small tip You can produce your data frame easier using `data.frame(x = rnorm (1:1000), y =rnorm (1:1000))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the area of ellipse drawn by ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782051/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-ellipse-drawn-by-ggplot2)

Comment: @DanielMuñoz that SO post is linked in my question, it is what I am asking about

Comment: @OliviaJean aaa I understand you friend, sorry is that I had not understood you well

Answer (score 1):

Nice question, I learned something. But I cannot reproduce your problem and get (of course) different values with the different approaches.

I think the approach in the linked answer is not quite correct because the ellipse center is not calculated with the data, but based on the ellipse coordinates. I have updated to calculate this based on the data.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:1000), y = rnorm(1:1000))

p_norm <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse(type = "norm")

pb <- ggplot_build(p_norm)
el <- pb$data[[2]][c("x", "y")]
ctr <- MASS::cov.trob(data)$center #updated previous answer here
dist2center <- sqrt(rowSums((t(t(el) - ctr))^2))
pi * min(dist2center) * max(dist2center)
#> [1] 18.40872
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**update** thanks to Axeman for the thoughts.

The area can be directly calculated from the covariance matrix by calculating the eigenvalues first. You need to scale the variances / eigenvalues by the factor of confidence that you want to get. 
[This blog helped me a lot to understand this a bit better](https://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/draw-error-ellipse-representing-covariance-matrix/)

```r
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:1000), y = rnorm(1:1000))

cov_dat <- cov(dat) # covariance matrix

eig_dat <- eigen(cov(dat))$values #eigenvalues of covariance matrix

vec <- sqrt(5.991* eig_dat) # half the length of major and minor axis for the 95% confidence ellipse

pi * vec[1] * vec[2]  
#> [1] 18.38858
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**In this particular case, the covariances are zero**, and the eigenvalues will be more or less the variance of the variables. So you can use just the variance for your calculation. - given that both are normally distributed.

```r
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:1000), y = rnorm(1:1000))

pi * 5.991 * sd(data$x) * sd(data$y) # factor for 95% confidence = 5.991
#> [1] 18.41814
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**The factor 5.991** represents the Chi-square likelihood for the 95% confidence of the data. For more information, [see this thread](https://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/draw-error-ellipse-representing-covariance-matrix/)

Comment: I think you should be able to get the area from just the covariance matrix given by `cov.wt`, although not sure how. But, you can definately avoid all the ggplot stuff by using `car::ellipse` directly on the covariance matrix.

Comment: @Axeman Here we go. Ignore my last comment. See my updated answer for calculation based on the covariance matrix. I think this would be the way to go. In this particular case one can simly use the variable variance

Comment: Awesome! Can you clarify where the 5.991 comes from?

Comment: @Axeman It represents the chi-square likelihood - this is based on a few assumptions on the data, here mainly normal distribution. I found the thread linked in the answer very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get `a` and `b` (then the area is `pi*a*b`) without using the data generated by `stat_ellipse`.

```
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse(type = "norm", segments = 2000)

Sigma <- cov(faithful) 
evalues <- eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE)$values
p <- 0.95
r <- 2 * qf(p, 2, nrow(faithful)-1)
( a <- sqrt(r * evalues[1]) )
# 33.55752
( b <- sqrt(r * evalues[2]) )
# 1.216351

### check
ggb <- ggplot_build(gg)
el <- ggb$data[[2]][c("x","y")]
center <- colMeans(faithful)
dist2center <- sqrt(rowSums((t(t(el)-center))^2))
max(dist2center)
# 33.55751
min(dist2center)
# 1.216396
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with using the code from the ellipse package using the quakes dataset. Its a lot longer but simpler to understand how it works (at least for me). I believe the area solution is in meters squared. Any thoughts on this approach?

```
#Both plots together
Bothgg <- ggplot(quakes, aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse(type = "t")+    #type = "t" is unnecessary because it is the default, but I put it here for clarity
  stat_ellipse(type = "norm", linetype = 2)
Bothgg



###From ellipses code
dfn <- 2
dfd <- nrow(quakes) - 1
segments = 51
level = .95

#Area for solid line
  v <- MASS::cov.trob(quakes[ ,c(1,2)])
  shape <- v$cov
  center <- v$center
  chol_decomp <- chol(shape)
  radius <- sqrt(dfn * stats::qf(level, dfn, dfd))
  angles <- (0:segments) * 2 * pi/segments
  unit.circle <- cbind(cos(angles), sin(angles))
  ellipse <- as.data.frame(t(center + radius * t(unit.circle %*% chol_decomp)))
  centerd = as.data.frame(center)
  ellipse$centerLat = centerd[1,1]
  ellipse$centerLong = centerd[2,1]
  ellipse$distance = distm(ellipse[,c('long','lat')], ellipse[,c('centerLong','centerLat')], fun=distVincentyEllipsoid)
pi*(min(ellipse$distance)/2)*(max(ellipse$distance)/2)


#Area for dashed line
  v <- stats::cov.wt(quakes[ ,c(1,2)])
  shape <- v$cov
  center <- v$center
  chol_decomp <- chol(shape)
  radius <- sqrt(dfn * stats::qf(level, dfn, dfd))
  angles <- (0:segments) * 2 * pi/segments
  unit.circle <- cbind(cos(angles), sin(angles))
  ellipse <- as.data.frame(t(center + radius * t(unit.circle %*% chol_decomp)))
  centerd = as.data.frame(center)
  ellipse$centerLat = centerd[1,1]
  ellipse$centerLong = centerd[2,1]
  ellipse$distance = distm(ellipse[,c('long','lat')], ellipse[,c('centerLong','centerLat')], fun=distVincentyEllipsoid)
pi*(min(ellipse$distance)/2)*(max(ellipse$distance)/2)
```